# want to read data from textfile having certain pattern and populate the text boxes accordingly

Tags: asp.net, text-files

This is my Text File

R3073101.txt

3070004626!@!JAVEED BASHIR BURZA#@#BASHIR BURZA#@#502 BLUE BELLS FLOWER VALLEY NEAR#@#PAYYEDE HOTEL NAYA NAGAR#@#MIRA ROAD EAST THANE#@#401107#@#502 BLUE BELLS FLOWER VALLEY NEAR#@#PAYYEDE HOTEL NAYA NAGAR#@#MIRA ROAD EAST THANE#@#401107#@#1#@#1#@#N#@#15#@#114#@#FORD FIGO 1 4  EXI#@#4#@#1399#@#5#@#0#@#1525#@#0#@#2#@#MAJ1XXMRJ1DU78421#@#MAJ1XXMRJ1DU78421#@#C01#@#K BLUE#@#1#@#2014#@#1/30/2029#@#307#@#1#@#O#@##@#PV#@##@#541137#@##@##@#1/31/2014#@#0#@#1399#@#0#@#0#@#0#@#0#@##@##@##@##@##@##@#1/31/2014#@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@#NE#@#1#@#1/31/2014#@#1/30/2015#@#71050131130100129567#@#HP><401107><1/31/2014#@#
3070004627!@!SAJID PERVEZ#@#ALEY AHMED#@#1005/6 10TH FLR MEGHDOOT A 121#@#LOKHANDWALA COMPLEX#@#ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI#@#400053#@#1005/6 10TH FLR MEGHDOOT A 121#@#LOKHANDWALA COMPLEX#@#ANDHERI WEST MUMBAI#@#400053#@#1#@#1#@#N#@#15#@#114#@#FORD ECOSPORT 1 5 P TITA AT#@#4#@#1499#@#5#@#0#@#1700#@#0#@#1#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL12244#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL12244#@#C01#@#D WHITE#@#1#@#2014#@#1/30/2029#@#307#@#N#@#O#@##@#PV#@##@#952517#@##@##@#1/31/2014#@#0#@#1499#@#0#@#0#@#0#@#0#@##@##@##@##@##@##@#1/31/2014#@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@#IL#@#1#@#1/31/2014#@#1/30/2015#@#I24131022#@#
3070004628!@!ABRAR MALIK#@#SARDAR MALIK#@#A/703 PANCHTANTRA APT-II#@#PANCH MARG VERSOVA#@#MUMBAI#@#400061#@#A/703 PANCHTANTRA APT-II#@#PANCH MARG VERSOVA#@#MUMBAI#@#400061#@#1#@#1#@#N#@#15#@#114#@#FORD ECOSPORT 1 5 P AMB MT#@#4#@#1499#@#5#@#0#@#1700#@#0#@#1#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL15204#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL15204#@#C01#@#D WHITE#@#1#@#2014#@#1/30/2029#@#307#@#1#@#O#@##@#PV#@##@#653670#@##@##@#1/31/2014#@#0#@#1499#@#0#@#0#@#0#@#0#@##@##@##@##@##@##@#1/31/2014#@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@#IL#@#1#@#1/31/2014#@#1/30/2015#@#PS11225946#@#HP><400059><1/31/2014#@#
3070004629!@!A V B AMARAN#@#BABU ANTHONY CHETTY#@#B/203 DRONAGIRI MODERN USHA COLONY#@#EVERSHINE NAGAR MALAD WEST#@#MUMBAI#@#400064#@#B/203 DRONAGIRI MODERN USHA COLONY#@#EVERSHINE NAGAR MALAD WEST#@#MUMBAI#@#400064#@#1#@#1#@#N#@#15#@#114#@#FORD ECOSPORT 1 5 P AMB MT#@#4#@#1499#@#5#@#0#@#1700#@#0#@#1#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL15207#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL15207#@#C01#@#M SILVER#@#1#@#2014#@#1/30/2029#@#307#@#1#@#O#@##@#PV#@##@#653670#@##@##@#1/31/2014#@#0#@#1499#@#0#@#0#@#0#@#0#@##@##@##@##@##@##@#1/31/2014#@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@#NE#@#1#@#1/31/2014#@#1/30/2015#@#71050131130100129516#@#HP><3RD FLR A-WING TRADE STAR BLDG><400059><1/31/2014#@#
3070004630!@!NAROTTAM KUMAR SHARMA#@#PARMANAND SHARMA#@#103-B ASTER TOWER FILM CITY ROAD#@#FILM CITY ROAD MALAD EAST#@#MUMBAI#@#400097#@#103-B ASTER TOWER FILM CITY ROAD#@#FILM CITY ROAD MALAD EAST#@#MUMBAI#@#400097#@#1#@#1#@#N#@#15#@#114#@#FORD ECOSPORT 1 0 P TITA  MT#@#4#@#999#@#5#@#0#@#1700#@#0#@#1#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL17257#@#MAJAXXMRKAEL17257#@#C01#@#CHILL#@#1#@#2014#@#1/30/2029#@#307#@#1#@#O#@##@#PV#@##@#895890#@##@##@#1/31/2014#@#0#@#999#@#0#@#0#@#0#@#0#@##@##@##@##@##@##@#1/31/2014#@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@##@#IL#@#1#@#1/31/2014#@#1/30/2015#@#I-24134004#@#HP><400098><1/31/2014#@#

my .aspx code

```
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div align="left">
        <h3>
            <b>New Customer </b>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="input-group date"  data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" id="datetimepicker1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="span2" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Customer Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Name" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Customer Name Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Regn No</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Regn No" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Regn No Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Imv</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Imv" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="IMV Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Registration Cho</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Registration Cho" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Registration CHO Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Crtem Fees</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Crtem Fees" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Crtem Fees Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox6" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Crtem S.C</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Crtem S.C" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Crtem S.C Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                SOC</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter SOC" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="SOC Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Soc S.C
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Soc S.C" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Soc S.c Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Spl No.fees
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Spl No.Fees" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Spl No.fees Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox10" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Spl No.s.c
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Spl No.s.c" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Spl No.s.c Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox11" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Total No
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Total No" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Total No Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox12" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                No.5
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter No.5" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ErrorMessage="No.5 Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox13" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Redium
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Redium" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Redium Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox14" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                W.V
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter W.V" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" ErrorMessage="W.V Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox15" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                TAX
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter TAX" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" runat="server" ErrorMessage="TAX Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox16" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Int
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Int" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Int Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox17" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                CF
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter CF" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CF Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox18" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Above 10 Lacs
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox19" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Above 10 lacs" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Above 10 Lacs Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox19" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                Total
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox20" runat="server" Placeholder="Enter Total" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator20" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Total Required"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox20" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 176px">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                    ValidationGroup="val1" Height="40px" Width="89px" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 176px">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                     Height="40px" Width="89px" 
                    onclick="Button2_Click" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

On the Click of update button my text boxes should get populated according to there name like for ex-: in text file it has first 3070004626=Sr.no!@!JAVEED BASHIR BURZA=name ,like javeed bashir burza should get populated to textbox1.text

Thanks in Advace.

Comment: yes we know you want something, show also what you tried.

Comment: it seems like @ is separating your values and # is around your strings, you might need to readline from your file, split on @ and then you can get values and assign to your controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of your txt Files is the same all over you can use this query in your `button_Click()` method:

```
var result = from txt in File.ReadAllLines(@"/path/to/your/file")
             let column = txt.Split(new [] {'!', '@','#'}).Where (t => t.Length > 0 )
             select column.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

//Output: JAVEED BASHIR BURZA
textbox1.Text = result.First();
```

*EDIT*

If you need all elements and want to iterate over them use the following code:

```
var result = from txt in File.ReadAllLines(@"/path/to/your/file")
             let column = txt.Split(new [] {'!', '@','#'}).Where (t => t.Length > 0 )
             select column;

foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Comment: i want a forr loop and i want to display data of all lines

Comment: var result = from txt in File.ReadAllLines(@"/path/to/your/file")
             let column = txt.Split(new [] {'!', '@','#'}).Where (t => t.Length > 0 )
             select column;

foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}

how to replace Console.Writeline with textbox1.text with array index of file

Comment: This is way beyond of what you originally asked. Please ask another question with ONE excact problem.

Comment: var result = from txt in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\R3073101.txt")
                         let column = txt.Split(new[] { '!', '@', '#' }).Where(t => t.Length > 0)
                         select column;

            foreach (var element in result)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = element.ToString();
            }

Sir i have replaced this code of yours but still am not getting exact output some were i am missing something guide me

Comment: i am not getting the exact output with your second example first one was giving the output but i want it in foreach loop, i am missing soomething ....